# Automation Testing tools

Tags: .net, backbone.js, selenium, automation, automated-tests

I have an application in .net having Backbone + Javascript UI & at service side Asp.Net Web API, Entity Framework and SQL Server.

I want to test whole application with automation tool. I am new in automation testing. Kindly provide your suggesting in available testing tool which will fit into my criteria.

Comment: I've had a good experience testing a Backbone UI with [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/)

Comment: So, It's a web app which runs on browser. You can choose a Web automated testing tool(s).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some good tools as per your requirement given below :

1 - Selenium IDE , Selenium web driver - For functionality testing.

2 - Jmeter - For Load / Stress testing

Using selenium web driver you can create automatic script for all functionality which are in your site. You need to create script once only then it will be easy to run in future for re-testing / Regression testing of same functionality.

Jmeter will help you to measure capacity of your system/site , database and a lot more.

Helpful links :

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

http://jmeter.apache.org/

http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/

Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Kindly provide me more info. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think I have given you link of all basic things you need. Now I can help you more if share any specific requirements.

Comment: Ok. Let me read info from links and get back to you for any specific queries. :)